# Pyspark | Seperate the string / int values from the dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark Dataframe as below:

```
+---------+
|col_str_1|
+---------+
|     1|
|     2|
|     3|
|     4|
|     5|
|     6|
|     7|
|     8|
|     9|
|     a|
|     b|
|     c|
|     d|
|     e|
|     f|
|     g|
|     h|
|     1|
|     2|
|   3.0|
+---------+
```

I want to separate the string / int / float values based on request

For Example: 
Req is for STRING, return DF must be like below

```
+---------+
|col_str_1|
+---------+
|     a|
|     b|
|     c|
|     d|
|     e|
|     f|
|     g|
|     h|
+---------+
```

Req is for Integer, return DF must be like below

```
+---------+
|col_str_1|
+---------+
|     1|
|     2|
|     3|
|     4|
|     5|
|     6|
|     7|
|     8|
|     9|
|     1|
|     2|
+---------+
```

Tried below steps:

```
>> df = sqlContext.sql('select * from --db--.vt_prof_test') 
>> columns = df.columns[0]
>> df.select(columns).????
```

how to proceed further, either use filter or map, can any one help me out ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go for `udf`

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = sqlContext.sql('select * from --db--.vt_prof_test') 

REQUEST = 'STRING'
request_bc = sc.broadcast(REQUEST)

def check_value(val):
    if request_bc.value == 'STRING':
        try:
            val = int(val)
            return None
        except:
            return val
    if request_bc.value == 'INTEGER':
        try:
            val = int(val)
            return val
        except:
            return None

check_udf = F.udf(lambda x: check_value(x))

df = df.select(check_udf(F.col('col_str_1').alias('col_str_1')).dropna()
```

Set the `REQUEST` parameter according to the need.

Comment: Thanks Mayank, this has saved my DAYS